# Cannot boot into Windows 8 after successful Ubuntu installation

Tags: boot, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed UEFI Supported Windows 8 system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

Recently I've tried to install Ubuntu in a partition of a hard-drive that also has Windows 8.  I've done this on a Windows 7 computer before, so I figured this would be done similarly.  I installed it using a Ubuntu USB drive.  When I attempt to boot in Windows 8, a quick _ gets displayed, and then I get moved back to the boot screen where I can select what I wish to boot from.
Here is my fdisk -l output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 256.1 GB, 256060514304 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 31130 cylinders, total 500118192 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xdec26e36

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048      144584       71268+  de  Dell Utility
/dev/sda2          145408    18057059     8955826    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3   *    18057216   437300047   209621416    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       437301246   500117503    31408129    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       437301248   492031999    27365376   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       492034048   500117503     4041728   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

I do have several extra partitions on the hard-drive for work related reasons as well, so treat any extra non-linux related partitions as such.  As you can see, my Windows partition is still in-tact, as well as sda1 - sda6.
I can also view my Windows partition using this Ubuntu version.
Does anyone have any idea why I am unable to boot into Windows 8?
Any help would be appreciated, as I need to do work on both Windows 8 and Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Have you resized the Windows partition, especially the Windows boot partition during the Ubuntu installation? If so, that might be the cause of the problem. I had this problem with Windows 7 on an OEM system after installing Ubuntu if I deleted Windows's boot partition.

Booting from the Windows installation medium (DVD or USB flash drive with your Windows ISO image written to it) and using its recovery tools to perform automatic repair may help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the win8 Cd I would try inserting the disc into drive and trying to repair the OS that way, seems to me like you overwrote the win8 system32 data

Comment: But remember that doing so would overwrite grub2, requiring you to run boot repair before Ubuntu will be able to boot again.